# Missing tile endpoint in OpenMapTiles -> Mapbox GL JS example

Tags: openstreetmap, mapbox-gl-js

OpenMapTiles.org gives an [example snippet](https://openmaptiles.org/docs/website/mapbox-gl-js/) (which is described as) showing how to use Mapbox GL JS to display openmaptiles generated tiles.

The full OMT example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>OpenMapTiles OSM Bright style</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.29.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'https://openmaptiles.github.io/osm-bright-gl-style/style-cdn.json',
            center: [8.5456, 47.3739],
            zoom: 11
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I serve it from an *nginx* server and it does indeed work.

The path to the *tiles* is fairly deep however:

```
https://openmaptiles.github.io/osm-bright-gl-style/style-cdn.json
...
sources:
  openmaptiles: 
    type:  "vector"
    url: "https://free.tilehosting.com/data/v3.json?key=RiS4gsgZPZqeeMlIyxFo"
...

https://free.tilehosting.com/data/v3.json?key=RiS4gsgZPZqeeMlIyxFo
tiles:
  0:"https://maps.tilehosting.com/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf.pict?key=RiS4gsgZPZqeeMlIyxFo"
```

I have two questions:

1. The above final tile endpoint `https://maps.tilehosting.com/data/v3/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf.pict` appears from the suffix `.pict` not be a vector format.  Is that correct?  Is there another example using the vector format produced by the tools in openmaptiles git repo?
2. Is the chain of files leading to the tiles endpoint all open software, or is some of it proprietary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regarding your first question:**

`.pbf.pict` is just an alias for `.pbf` which could be set in the [configuration file](http://tileserver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) of [Tileserver GL](https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl) which I think is used for serving the OMT vector tiles in this case.

Some more information regarding `.pbf.pict`:

- https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl/issues/109
- https://github.com/klokantech/tileserver-gl/issues/253

**Regarding your second question:**

https://openmaptiles.github.io/osm-bright-gl-style/style-cdn.json

is the following [Mapbox GL style](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/):

https://github.com/openmaptiles/osm-bright-gl-style

https://github.com/openmaptiles/osm-bright-gl-style/blob/master/style.json

License:

https://github.com/openmaptiles/osm-bright-gl-style/blob/master/LICENSE.md

This style references the [sources](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources) which could be used for the map.